# Windows phone navigation bug

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I encountered an issue.
I have a loading page with progress bar. It is non-interactive, it only shows progress on loading data. AFter data is loaded - it navigates to MenuPage.

If user minimizes app during loading process sometimes a phantom corrupted entry is added to BackStack.

Problem:
If this corrupted entry is in backstack - `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` throws `NullReferenceException`.

Question:
My goal is to exit app from 2nd page when user presses back. Can i somehow do that without removing items from backstack and throwing exceptions ?

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need a separate page to display the progress as opposed to having the progress bar display on the page that initiated the load?  Then you don't have to muck with the backstack at all.

Comment: Main reason for that was separation of responsibilities. Not to make mess in code. The second is that MenuPage (that is shown after loading data) is quite heavy (coz of big Panorama)

Comment: I do this in my production app using a different UI control which is shown on top of the Panorama when my app is loading. It works well. Just use two different ViewModels, and it'll be like it never even happened!

Comment: Yeah, seems that i'll have to refactor code for that. Thank you guys.

Answer (score -2):

In short, no. You can't directly quit an application and it sucks. However you can do it with a well handled exception.

```
private class QuitException : Exception { }

public static void Quit()
{
    throw new QuitException();
}

private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, 
ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ExceptionObject is QuitException)
        return;

    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Source:

http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/22/How-to-Quit-a-WP7-Silverlight-Application.aspx

Comment: This is completely inacceptable solution. Application with such code won't pass Microsoft+Nokia review. Im also not sure about usual marketplace certification. And of course seeing thousands of unhandled exceptions in marketplace crash report is not very nice.

Comment: What? It is a perfectly acceptable solution. This answers the question and there are NO other ways of doing this.

Comment: Read the question again. You'll notice that i asked about solution without exceptions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I apologise. Should I delete my answer?